# Using FontAwesome as css pseudo background results in blurry icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I would like to use FontAwesome icons as css backgrounds. However the end result is a blurry, or rather, fattened icon. I have tried a few things like font-smoothing etc but no luck. How can I make css background icons look as sharp as when used inline html?

```
<h5>With CSS:before background</h5>
<a href="#" class="back"></a>
<h5>With icon in DOM</h5>
<a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-white fa-2x"></i></a>

<style>
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
a.back:before {
  content: "\f167";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;

}
</style>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/kdta4zak/

Also attached a shot. Results are the same in FF, Chrome and Safari.
[image]

Comment: looks okay in Firefox but in chrome  both method are a little blurry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK to me in all browsers. However, I was able to improve it slightly by explicitly setting the `text-decoration` of the pseudo-element to "none", rather than the "inherit" you are using.

Comment: you beat me to the answer. I advice that you remove that line entirely.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6rna6v Comparing the rest of the fonts in your Fiddle to the ones in your screenshot and they're all much clearer on my machine so you may want to adjust your OS's font settings.

Comment: `text-decoration` doesnt make a diff for me. But from the comments it does sound like an isolated problem which is good though Id like to know why 2 fonts dont show up the same regardless of my settings

Answer (score 1):

Ok - more playing with font smoothing solved it for all 3 browsers.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
```

Evidently this may be an issue with only some people - perhaps font setting on computer. I am on OSX 10.10.3.